# PHP Merge Elements With Same First Element Adding Second

Tags: php

I'm attempting to aggregate statistics for users last month of visiting venues and I have it so it returns an array as below

```
[["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 6",1],["Apr 7",1],["Apr 7",1],["Apr 7",1],["Apr 13",1],["Apr 14",1],["Apr 15",1],["Apr 15",1],["Apr 15",1],["Apr 16",1],["Apr 16",1],["Apr 16",1],["Apr 16",1],["Apr 16",1],["Apr 16",1],["Apr 16",1],["Apr 17",1],["Apr 17",1],["Apr 17",1],["Apr 17",1],["Apr 20",1],["Apr 20",1],["Apr 20",1],["Apr 20",1],["Apr 21",1],["Apr 27",1],["Apr 27",1],["Apr 27",1],["Apr 27",1],["Apr 27",1],["Apr 28",1],["Apr 28",1],["Apr 29",1],["Apr 29",1],["Apr 30",1],["Apr 30",1],["May 4",1],["May 4",1],["May 4",1]]
```

I'd like to merge all dates together, incrementing the number in the first element, so for this specific array it would show `[["Apr 6", 12]` for `Apr 6`

Is there any way to do this built in to PHP or an easier way to do this?

Thanks

- Zach

Edit - My Current Code:

```
$now = Carbon::now()->setTimezone($this->timezone);
      $start = Carbon::now()->setTimezone($this->timezone);
      $end = $now->subWeek()->subWeek();
      $barStats = $this->barStats()->get();
      $tempReturn = [];
      $finalReturn = [];
      foreach($barStats as $barStat) {
        $timeArrived = Carbon::parse($barStat->timeArrived, $this->timezone);
        if($timeArrived->between($start, $end)) {
          $tempReturn[] = [substr($timeArrived->format('F'), 0, 3) . " $timeArrived->day", 1];
        }
      }
      foreach($tempReturn as $return) {
        if(!in_array($return[0], $finalReturn)) {
          $finalReturn[] = [$return[0], array_count_values($tempReturn, 1)];
        }
      }
      return $finalReturn;
```

Comment: Are all the values in the inner arrays always going to be 1? (Asking because it's slightly easier to count rather than sum)

Comment: Create an associative array whose keys are the dates, and then add the second element to the values.

Comment: If the values are all 1: `array_count_values(array_column($array, 0))`

Comment: @Barmar I attempted to solve it myself, but I was unsure of how to word the question when Googling or Searching to get the correct answer, the values are always going to be 1 as I assumed I could count them

Comment: What does Google have to do with solving it yourself? To solve it yourself you just write code using your basic knowledge of PHP arrays and looping.

Comment: So how would I use the `array_count_values` to merge the elements with the same first index? I can put my code in the beginning, but I didn't include it to try to simplify the question

Comment: Added my code to the question for clarification

Comment: Have you considered doing this with a query on your database instead of your code? Something like this you could do a group by on the root table ID and then count the number of rows for each date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to do in one pass this without `$tempReturn`. You can just use the day as the key in the final result and increment as you go:

```
foreach($barStats as $barStat) {
    $timeArrived = Carbon::parse($barStat->timeArrived, $this->timezone);
    if ($timeArrived->between($start, $end)) {

        // get the day
        $day = substr($timeArrived->format('F'), 0, 3) . " $timeArrived->day";

        // use it as the key in $finalReturn
        if (!isset($finalReturn[$day])) {
            $finalReturn[$day] = [$day, 0];
        }
        $finalReturn[$day][1]++;
    }
}

// remove the string keys if necessary
$finalReturn = array_values($finalReturn);
```

---

By the way, I don't really know Carbon so there may be some other reason you're doing it that way, but it looks like the date formatting could be simplified to

```
$day = $timeArrived->format('M j');
```

Comment: I had to `array_values` the final result but it worked! Thank you!